# What is the $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ in Wavelets analysis?

Tags: fourier-analysis, information-theory, signal-processing, wavelets, compression

I am studying wavelets and somenthing that catch my attention is the existance of a so caled scaling function $\Phi$. Let's take the Haar wavelet. I do not understand why is the scalling function different from the wavelet itself, after all they are both needed for a base right? I really want to understand why is there and why is different to the wavelet.

So far what I have noticed is that the $\Phi$ function is always the low-pass filter, but still do not get the name and the implicance.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You may get more of a response by moving this post to dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you very much!